# Golang HTTPS with ECDSA certificate from OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, go, openssl, ecdsa

I don't know if this is the correct place to ask it, but I will try.

I am trying to run `http.ListenAndServeTLS` with ECDSA certificate generated from OpenSSL.

It fail with this error message: `tls: failed to parse private key`

Go understand `elliptic.P256()`, in the code it has this comment `See FIPS 186-3, section D.2.3`.

In this link: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5480.txt, it says it is also called `secp256r1`.

As you can see below, OpenSSL undestand this as `prime256v1`.

```
$ openssl ecparam -name secp256r1 -text -noout
using curve name prime256v1 instead of secp256r1
ASN1 OID: prime256v1
NIST CURVE: P-256
```

So what is wrong?
How can I generate ECDSA certificate from OpenSSL and use it on my Go code?

Using `generate_cert.go` to generate a P256 ECDSA certificate, my code works, but if I try to read the key file with OpenSSL it fail also.

```
$ openssl ecparam -text -noout -in key.pem 
unable to load elliptic curve parameters
140377431725720:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: EC PARAMETERS
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, but when the public key of the target server is parsed. Therefore, I cannot generate a new certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figured out what is the problem between OpenSSL and Go.

But my main problem is, how to generate ECDSA certificate to use with Go code!

Using `CFSSL` (https://cfssl.org/) I can generate ECDSA certificate and sign it with my internal CA certificate generated from OpenSSL. The certificate generated from `CFSSL` works fine with my Go code, so for me it solves my main problem!

I don't know if there is a format problem between OpenSSL and Go, but as `CFSSL` is written in Go, the certificate generated on it works fine in my code and in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of OpenSSL generated ECDSA keys working with Go.

https://play.golang.org/p/MS_FQ8cqqA8.

As clarified in this issue - https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23591, go does not recognize EC keys that are generated with the `-param_enc explicit` flag in Openssl.

`# openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out priv2.pem`

`# openssl req -new -x509 -key priv2.pem -out EC_server2.pem -days 365`

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I don't know if it was an issue with my old Go version or with OpenSSL, but now even my old code works. Now I am using the latest Go version: `1.9.3`

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
go run `go env GOROOT`/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go --host=localhost --ecdsa-curve=P256
```

This will generate `cert.pem` and `key.pem` in the current directory.